# BASH - Add timestamp to output of mysql cli commands

Tags: bash, shell

i need to log output of mysql cli commands with timestamp to check connectivity issues. I write this:

```
echo "$(date -u) - $(mysql -u${DATABASE_USER} -p${DATABASE_PASSWORD} -h ${WRONG_HOST} -e 'quit')" >> /check_RDS.log
```

I see into log file

`tue  6 dec 2018, 10.37.04, UTC -`

instead of

`tue  6 dec 2018, 10.37.04, UTC - ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (111)`

I tried also with `ts`

`mysql -u${DATABASE_USER} -p${DATABASE_PASSWORD} -h ${WRONG_HOST} -e 'quit' | ts`

result is:

`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (111)`

How i can append date on the same line of log?

Comment: You should check whether the error message is written on stdout or stderr. If it's stderr, you'll need to redirect it to stdout in order for the `$(...)` to be expanded into the message rather than to an empty stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter which method you use, you need to append a `2>&1` after the `mysql ...` command. This is because the pipe as well as the command substitution only use the stdin and the stderr will just be displayed on the console.

```
echo "$(date -u) - $(mysql -u${DATABASE_USER} -p${DATABASE_PASSWORD} -h ${WRONG_HOST} -e 'quit' 2>&1)" >> /check_RDS.log
```

or

```
mysql -u${DATABASE_USER} -p${DATABASE_PASSWORD} -h ${WRONG_HOST} -e 'quit' 2>&1 | ts
```

But even better than `echo "... $(mysql -u ... 2>&1)"` would be to write the output directly to the file. As described in [tamasgal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53649643/5092659).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `echo -n "$(date -u) - " >> check_RDS.log` and then your `mysql` command.

`echo -n` will prevent a new line, so the next line will be "appended".

The other issue you mentioned is the different handling of streams (stdout and stderr).

```
mysql.. >> check_RDS.log 2>&1
```

will combine both of them.

Comment: I've try with: `echo "$(date -u) - " >> /check_RDS.log && echo -n "$(mysql -u${DATABASE_USER} -p${DATABASE_PASSWORD} -h ${WRONG_HOST} -e 'quit')" >> /check_RDS.log 2>&1` but in the log file have only: `tue  6 dec 2018, 11.31.06, UTC -`